# Proxy authentication required java httpclient

Tags: java, proxy, httpclient

I create client with this code:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager manager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
manager.setMaxTotal(9999);
manager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(9999);

String proxyHost = proxy.split(":")[0];
Integer proxyPort = Integer.parseInt(proxy.split(":")[1]);
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password);
CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort), credentials );

authClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(manager)
        .setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort))
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credProvider)
        .setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy())
        .setConnectionTimeToLive(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

But this configuration returns 407 status code.

Comment: Are you able to use the same proxy and credentials from the browser ?

Comment: @11thdimension yes